# Font Width Ratios: GetTextExtent32 versus Word and PDF

Tags: winapi, fonts

GetTextExtent32 returns different character width ratios (e.g., width of '9' versus space) than Word or Acrobat use when displaying the same font (e.g., 10-point Arial).

This matters because I'm trying to prepare clipboard strings that will get pasted into apps that don't support much formatting (no tabs or tables), but I still need to align certain columns of info.  I'm trying to overcome this challenge by dynamically calculating the number of spaces I need to insert (remember, no tabs allowed!).

For example, calling GetTextExtent32 with a selected font of Arial 10-point gives a logical unit width of 7 for the digit '9', and a logical unit width of 4 for a space. This ratio proves correct when using something like DrawText.

However, when I export strings to Word or Acrobat, it turns out that 2 spaces in this example font exactly equals the width of one 9 (whether looking at a single 9, or nine contiguous 9s).  I don't know much about fonts, but it doesn't appear to be any kind of juxtaposition issue; GetCharABCWidths shows 0 for both the a and c widths.

Does anyone know why Word and Acrobat are not showing the same proportions/measurements for a given font as Windows itself?  Is there are a way to calculate this?

Comment: Don't use spaces to align text. This will never work properly. Use `\t` characters and [`TabbedTextOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145129.aspx).

Comment: As I tried to describe in my previous first sentence, I cannot use tab characters because the strings I'm preparing are for external apps that don't support tabs. I can't use TabbedTextOut because I'm not displaying things anywhere: I'm constructing strings that go on the clipboard.  I've edited the question to try to make this clearer.

Comment: You also state that this is for certain applications that do not support tabs or tables, yet you name Word and PDF, both of which support tabs and tables. Regardless, you cannot control your target application's text rendering, so you're either left with monospace fonts, or a less than perfect result.

Comment: You may be right that there's no solution; I'm certainly struggling.  It's interesting to me that both Word and PDF appear to render basic fonts in the same proportions, neither of which matches Windows. FYI, PDF text boxes and comments do not support tabs, even though they support other RTF formatting, which is (one of) the problem here.

Comment: Since your target applications support RTF you might want to try and place an RTF table in the clipboard: [How To Add Custom Table to the Clipboard to be Pasted into Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216676)